# How to get 5 most used Tags with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables Comment and Tag, one comment can have multiple tags.

```
Comment has (commentId, ICollection<Tag>)
Tag has (tagId, ICollection<Comment> Comment)
```

I need a LINQ sentence to return the 5 most used tags

Comment: Please share with us what have you tried so far and where did you stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
var tagsTop5 = dbContext.Tags
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Comment.Count)
    .Take(5);
```

If needed, add e.g. `.ToList()` to get a concrete list.

Comment: Even though your answer seems correct, there is a problem: We don't know the context. We don't know that the OP is looking for a solution which works with EF or (s)he uses different tool to retrieve data from database.

Comment: Finally I opted for adding a filed calledTimesUsed to simplify me things, sorry for  the inconvience guys, and thank you so much

Comment: Ok - I guess what you wrote means `a field called TimesUsed`